# Switching layout dynamically depending on aspect ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, layout

I've been searching for a long time without finding a proper answer to this question. Maybe because it can come up with the right keywords to search for.
However, I have a WinForm with a ElementHost containing some WPF (A UserControl). In WinForm can be resized and I want the WPF to have a different layout/view depending on if the window is in landscape or portrait mode.

What is the best way to design a layout like this in WPF?

I will do the detection of the window aspect ration in my winform OnResize(System.EventArgs e) and send the signal downwards into my ElementHost. The layout should be switched and replaced at runtime.

Pardon me if the terminology is not correct but I'm a bit new to the .NET framework.

Comment: I guess you're looking for a `WrapPanel`?

Comment: @HighCore As far as I can see WrapPanel only wraps my content. I want an entirely different layout depending on the aspect ration of the window. Think something like this: http://i.imgur.com/cmuaCBA.png